# What is $\int \frac{\delta F}{\delta u} \frac{\delta G}{\delta v} \, dx \; $?

Tags: functional-analysis, physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Given $F[u]$ and $G[v]$ are functionals of a real-valued function, what is
$$
  \int \frac{\delta F}{\delta u} \frac{\delta G}{\delta v} \, dx \quad ?
$$

I have encountered such expressions for example in ["Hamiltonian description of the ideal fluid"](http://www.ph.utexas.edu/~morrison/98RMP_morrison.pdf) by P. J. Morrison. There Poisson brackets for several systems (mostly some version of ideal fluid) are given, like
$$
  \{F, G\} = \int \left[\frac{\delta F}{\delta q} \cdot \frac{\delta G}{\delta \pi} - \frac{\delta G}{\delta q} \cdot \frac{\delta F}{\delta \pi} \right] \, d a^3 \qquad (119)
$$
$$
  \{F, G\} = - \int_D \frac{\delta F}{\delta u} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\delta G}{\delta u} \, d x \qquad (156)
$$
and, in general:
$$
  \{F, G\} = \int_D \frac{\delta F}{\delta \psi^i} \mathfrak{J}^{ij} \frac{\delta G}{\delta \psi^j} \, d \mu \qquad (169)
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are functionals of appropriate functions, $\mathfrak{J}$ is a certain operator.

Unfortunately it is not said what does it mean, or at least I overlooked it. Moreover, the biggest problem is that even types of expressions involved are not specified. I've tried to filled that gap.

Considering functions $u,v : M$ and functionals $F, G : M \to R$, $\; M$ being a manifold of certain kind of functions, functional derivative $D$:

$$D : (M \to R) \to M \to M \to R $$
$$ \left( \left(D \, F \right)\, u \right) \, [v] = \left[\frac{d}{d \varepsilon} F[u + \varepsilon v] \right]_{\varepsilon = 0}$$

thus $\delta F / \delta u$ stands likely for

$$(D \, F)(u) : M \to R.$$

Now 
$$
  \int_D \frac{\delta F}{\delta u} v \, d x := \left< \frac{\delta F}{\delta u}, v \right> := \left[\frac{d}{d \varepsilon} F[u + \varepsilon v]\right]_{\varepsilon = 0},
$$
that is to some sort of contraction, analogous to covector and vector, and integral notation is just a reference to a finite-dimensional case. Thus I believe

$$
  \int_D \frac{\delta F}{\delta u} \frac{\delta G}{\delta v} \, dx := \left[ \frac{\delta F}{\delta u}, \frac{\delta G}{\delta v} \right],
$$
where $[\,,]$ is some sort of scalar product. Indeed, I guess scalar product between functions is implied:
$$
  \left[u. v \right] := \int_D uv \, dx,
$$
but I don't see from
$$\langle \,, \rangle : M \to (M \to R) \to R $$
$$[\,,] : M \to M \to R $$
how $[\,,]$ can be lifted to act for two functional derivatives. That is I know the mapping from functions to functionals, but not vice versa. Probably given enough limitations on $M$ there is one? Maybe someone will point me an accessible, but rigorous introduction to a subject.

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134619/2451